# How do I put the "$_" string in a \section?

Tags: sectioning, characters

How do I put the "`$_`" string in a `\section`?

When I try `\section{$\_}` it gives me `Missing $ inserted` error.

When I try `\section{\$\_}` it gives me `Extra }, or forgotten $.` error.

When I try `\section{\verb|$_|}` it gives me `Argument of \@xtrplargoom has an extra }` error.

Comment: do you mean a real dollar sign, or the section sign?

Comment: The second is correct and doesn't give errors. You may want to say `\texttt{\$\_}`, but it's not relevant.

Comment: `\section{\$\_}` works for me.

Comment: @PeterisKrumins: sorry, I was too quick.

Comment: `\section{\$\_}` works for me, so you'll have to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: i have no problem with the second option. How are you compiling?

Answer (score 11):

Not an answer, but an explanation:

- "When I try `\section{$\_}` it gives me `Missing $ inserted` error."

  You are allowed math in `\section`, so `\section{This is $x$}` is no problem. In your case however, you don't have a closing `$`. Sure, you may not want it, but that's what TeX sees and therefore expects.
- "When I try `\section{\$\_}` it gives me `Extra }, or forgotten $` error."

  This works because escaping `$` and `_` removes their math-context.
- "When I try `\section{\verb|$_|}` it gives me `Argument of \@xtrplargoom has an extra }` error."

  You cannot pass verbatim content as an argument to a macro. See [Why doesn’t verbatim work within ...?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin) The link includes ways of using verbatim content as arguments in a number of ways, if that's what you're really after.

When working with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), you may also be interested in using [`\texorpdfstring{<TeX string>}{<PDF string>}`](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-160004.1.2). This is helpful if you have bookmarks (also associated with `\section` commands) that consist of a string containing ASCII characters.

And another question:

- Why is it that sometimes it could *not* work and then suddenly work?

  Well, when you use `\section{<stuff>}`, LaTeX actually does `\section[<stuff>]{<stuff>}` (since the complete syntax of the optional argument is used, even though you don't specify it). Therefore, `<stuff>` makes its way into your `.aux` file, used for processing labels, references and other ToC-related things. If "bad things" go in there, it could be that it takes a "correct" compile to clear it (even though there will still be errors from reading the "bad" `.aux`), followed by *another* "correct" compile to be error-free. When in doubt, you could start fresh by deleting the `.aux` file before compiling.

Comment: +1 for the explanation about the aux file. I think that this is what happened to Peteris.